# Linux thread affinity makes thread run slower

Tags: linux, pthreads, cpu, affinity

I am trying to improve cpu utilization and make thread run faster by setting thread's CPU affinity. Here is my code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM 100000000
void *randfun(void *arg)
{
    int i;

    clock_t start, end;

    start = clock();

    for(i=0; i<NUM; i++)
        ;

    end = clock();

    printf("cpu random: %fs\n", (double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return;
}

void *fun(void *arg)
{
    int process_id = (int)arg;
    cpu_set_t mask;
    cpu_set_t get;

    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(process_id, &mask);

    pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(mask), &mask);

    CPU_ZERO(&get);

    int ac_id = pthread_getaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(get), &get);

    if(ac_id < 0)
    {
        printf("set thread affinity failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    int i;

    clock_t start, end;

    start = clock();

    for(i=0; i<NUM; i++)
        ;

    end = clock();

    printf("cpu affinity: %fs\n", (double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    int num = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    pthread_t *tidset = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*num);

    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        pthread_create(tidset+i, NULL, (void*)fun, (void*)i);
    }

    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        pthread_join(tidset[i], NULL);
    }

    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        pthread_create(tidset+i, NULL, (void*)randfun, NULL);
    }

    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        pthread_join(tidset[i], NULL);
    }

    free(tidset);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the problem, after doing some tests, it seems that thread randfun always runs faster than thread fun, which has been set cpu affinity.

And this is my cpu info:

```
2  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4260U CPU @ 1.40GHz
1 physical id   : 0
1 address sizes : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
1 physical id   : 0
1 address sizes : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Trying to outguess the kernel is very, very hard. It has access to so much more information than you do.

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong. This: "I am trying to improve cpu utilization and make thread run faster by setting thread's CPU affinity". Your very starting premise is incorrect. There is no guarantee that CPU affinity in itself will have the effect you desire. Also you haven't explained how you came to the conclusion that one "runs faster" than the other. Looking at the output of printf does not tell you that definitively. So in summary, your premise and testing methodology may need some work.